# Sanding Screens vs Sandpaper for Cedar Deck sanding

Tags: deck, screens, refinishing

I am sanding my cedar deck.

The deck has been stained and in places it is worn away leaving bare cedar that has weathered and turned silver.

I have the sander for the weekend,  ( 12x18 ) inches and the only sheets I can find that size are sanding screens - 80 grit.

Will it work like 80 grit sandpaper and sand through the stain like sandpaper ?

Comment: it sounds like you have the wrong tool. rent a drum sander and get most of your weekend back.

Comment: I suspect that the device you have is a square buffer and includes a vacuum dust collection system. The screens should increase efficacy of dust capture, though screens may also not last as long. It's hard to tell without better details/photos of your equipment.

Comment: Many types of small sanders can use full sheets of sand paper divided down to the correct size.  Palm sanders use "quarter sheets"  some other forms can use strips.  But if you're doing a deck, you may want a belt sander, which is another specific type, and is sold to fit the aander.

Answer (score 0):

80 grit is 80 grit and will work to some level but I would be worried about the life of the abrasive. 80 should rip the old stain up well but is really rough and  screens on a deck sounds like the wrong tool to me.